# Who is the purple man?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-2

In many of the minigames there's a purple man who does very evil things. In the feed the kids minigame he is seen pulling up in a purple car, killing a child, then driving away.  In another scene, he is seen telling Foxy to go out to the stage, but when Foxy gets there, there are 5 small skulls. There's another where Freddy Fazbear has to stop the Purple Man, but the game crashes and says "no you can't".

Who is he?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Nobody really knows, he is only mentioned as the "purple person".**

**This is the Purple Person's car:**

[image]

**This is the Purple Person himsellf:**

[image]

(Images taken straight from the [wiki](http://freddy-fazbears-pizza.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Minigames?file=Purple_Person.png))

The wiki states that:

> As the player tries to serve cake to all six kids, a purple car will pull up outside and a purple person gets out, then proceeds to kill the sad child (who actually appears to stop crying and then cry even harder)

They refer to him several times only as the Purple Person, so his identity is actually unknown.

On the other hand, there are several theories for who the purple person is. One being he could be a security guard, or at least posing as one!

> It is implied someone is tampering with the animatronics beforehand, which explains their aggression... although, theories suggest that it's the Marionette that's tampering with them due to pixelated post-death minigames pinpointing it as the murderer... Or do they? A mysterious purple man appears in some of the mini-games. In the cake mini-game, he seemingly kills someone, in another he's there when Foxy runs into a room of dead kids, and he can also appear in the Marionette chase◊ wearing a badge. **The last one suggests the purple man was a security guard, or posing as one.** This poses some odd questions. For example, if the purple man was the one who killed the kids, but the Marionette was the one who brought the dolls to life, is it possible that the Marionette was trying to save the kids in the only way it could?

---

[Source](http://freddy-fazbears-pizza.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Minigames)

[Source 2](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/YMMV/FiveNightsAtFreddys2)

Comment: Game Theory just did a video on this, I suggest checking it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1kw1RmzrPc

Answer (score 1):

Here's my theory (it's pretty long):

So I think the purple man is phone guy, and I have VERY strong evidence

1. In fnaf 2 phone guy says you take the day shift and he will take the night shift, he also says to stay VERY close to them.
2. the date is 1987 (during the bite of 87) so he tampers with freddy (freddy was the animatronic that bit jeramy (player) cause in one of the halls theres a poster that says:RULES OF SAFETY: 1. blah 2. don't run 3. don't cry 4. blahs 5. jibber jabber 6. DO NOT TOUCH FREDDY) so you are the the one who was bitten.
3. PG (phone guy) did this because jeramy knew to much. He thought that if your frontal lobe was bitten, you would die and no one would know.
4. lastly, in the minigame where you are following the marrionett (and secretly saying "S-A-V-E-T-H-E-M") you see the pm (purple man) with a phone in his hand and he has a badge (which resembles he was a person who worked there) and when he touches u it will glich up and in the bottom left corner it says "you can't"

Answer (score 0):

It's the guard you played as in the first five nights at freddys thats why you have a different name it the second one

Answer (score 0):

The the purple person is a half man half a anomotronic he is the creator of the puppet.basicly he is still alive and is stuck in a suit

Answer (score 0):

I think Phone Guy is the killer because he is the only one with ties with the original restaurant and in the mini games found in Five Nights 2 actually show that first diner at one point—you only see the Freddy animatronic trying to take cake to a bunch of kids in the restaurant. The first restaurant that started it all was probably smaller than both the pizzerias found in 1 and 2, and to think they'd start with a single animatronic, too—Freddy himself . Assuming that's true, let's look at what happens in that mini game. As you give cake out to all the kids, you see another crying child that's separated from all the rest. Eventually a man in a car comes over and murders the kid. That kid ends up eventually to be The Puppet or Marionette. It's probably no coincidence that that same puppet attacks you after you play the mini game with the cake-less kid, too. Presumably it was this incident that prompted the owners of the original diner to sell to the company that ends up making Freddy Fazbear's Pizza. It's at this new restaurant where a murderer ends up taking out five children—the bodies are never found, though it's widely assumed these kids end up being stuffed inside the animatronics—hence the bad smell that the phone guy mentions to the player. This theory comes to prove that the souls of the children are tied to the animatronics by the puppet, since that's what one of the death mini games in FNAF 2 suggests. More interestingly, the mini games suggest that the guy that kills the group of children also killed the first kid in the diner. This explains why the animatronics would go on to have a safety measure that can identify sex offenders and criminals as well. For one, he seems to have a long history with the restaurants, including the first one. He doesn't seem to like the puppet animatronic, though he does mention liking the Foxy animatronic. One of the mini games shows the murderer watching Foxy with a smile. And more importantly, one of the mini games shows what appears to be a guard with a phone—and if he touches you, you can't save the kids...﻿

Comment: I think you just copied this from the new game theory video. Please do some real research, and if you're going to blatantly copy, at least put some though into it.

Answer (score 0):

Purple man (also known as purple guy) is a purple killer known for killing (10-15?) children. he is the man inside the springtrap suit. He is also responsible for destroying the animatronics in 1993 ( I believe ) and getting spring locked, stuck there for 30 years. I also have evidence.Faz bears fright is set in 2023, 1993+30=2023. He has been stuck there for 30 years. Proving my evidence. Now why does he kill children? Some people believe that he cannot control his sanity and a dark glitch is controlling him during the killing of the 5 missing children. The first 5 children were the spirits of the toy animatronics. Their names are unknown but people have given them names. The 5 children that we know have been murdered are Jeremy,Cassidy,Gabriel,Susie,and fritz. They control the OG animatronics. Also, some believe that he did it all himself and needs to suffer/pay for what he has done. There’s no way you can prove me wrong because it’s impossible for purple guy or William Afton to have died in 1992/1991/1990/1987. Because Fa bears fright is set in 2023, now here’s the important part you need to pay attention to. THE MINIGAMES. in one mini game (fnaf6 I think) the puppet is looking at children that look like they’re bald.but it says to not let the child with green on her hand. If you don’t let her in you can see her jumping asking for help as she fades away. To know what happened. You can see in one mini game fredbear or freddy giving cakes to children to make them happy. Except there’s a girl outside crying. That the girl with green on her hand. Also known as Charlie/Charlotte. And a purple car pulls by and murders her. That purple guy’s First ever target. In fnaf 3 main menu you can see springtrap is trying to get out of his suit. But he can’t. That’s William/purple guy escaping, but he can’t. In UCN.you play as William afton. Ever animatronic is there because your suffering and it’s your hell before going to ACTUAL HELL. Scrap trap,springtrap,burn trap are ALL William, even glitch trap.